# How do I remove duplicate quicklist?

Tags: 12.04, unity, nautilus, quicklists

Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit

When I right click on the Nautilus File icon in the Unity bar a quicklist appears; Documents, Pictures, etc.

This for some reason disapeared... I do not know why.. I guess a crash..

So I used Ubuntu Tweak to put them back...

However, after a reboot I now have multiple entries with no way to remove the extrra I added, they do not appear in any quicklist editor.

I tried, as suggested in another similar question this:

**Remove the old file:** 
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop

**Reinstall nautilus:** 
sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus

But this did not work..

I manually removed these files, then reinstalled nautilus, but on reboot the duplicates are back.

Does anyone know where the config files are held?

Can I manually edit?

What is strange the duplicate quicklists keep going and coming back..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `~/.local/share/applications/nautilus` as this is what is used by Unity.